# A badge in GitHub template repository that will refer to clones' build status, not the template repo's build status

Tags: github-actions

I'm new to GitHub's template repositories. We've created a template repo for our course's code labs. Let's say it's on GitHub under `myorg/labX`. The students are using GitHub Classroom, which clones the template repo for each student under `myorg/labX-studentlogin`. We've got actions to run some tests against their code using GitHub's own CI, and I want to include badges in the repo's README.md to see the test results at a glance. So I know that

```
![](https://github.com/myorg/labX/workflows/task1/badge.svg)
```

will include the badge, but this is the status of the template repo, not student repos. Is there a way to automate this so that when the students get their clone, it will contain a README with the URL that refers to the status of their own repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there is a simple solution, but only for GitHub's own Actions status badges. We've changed the image URL in our README.mds to relative. 
The only minor thing is GitHub will insert `/blob/<branch>/` into relative links when rendering the readmes.
For example, `workflows/task1/badge.svg` will become `https://github.com/myorg/labX/blob/master/workflows/task1/badge.svg`), which won't render. So we had to prepend `'../../'` to fool it.

**TLDR**: in repo's README.md, use

```
![](../../workflows/<workflowname>/badge.svg)
```

to get a badge for an Action status in this repo. This way, each student will get a badge referring to his own repo, not the template repo.

However, still looking for a way to use an external badge service like shields.io in a way relative to the repo.

Comment: Maybe GitHub has adjusted their repository layouts since you wrote this, but I had to do it as `![](../../actions/workflows/<workflowname>/badge.svg` (adding an `actions` subdirectory prior to `workflows`).

Answer (score 1):

I agree it would be a great feature to have.

It looks like at this point, GitHub Template Repositories do not support variable substitution, which is what would make it possible.

I see it is discussed briefly here:
[Variable substitution for GitHub Template Repository Usage](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Variable-substitution-for-GitHub-Template-Repository-Usage/td-p/44642)

Perhaps you should join the discussion and/or cast your Kudo.

Comment: Yes, as with any templating solution, substitution is what makes templates truly useful! Left a kudo, but probably would be better to open an issue or something. Though not likely to have substitution everywhere in the repo, I imagine adding it just to the READMEs should be pretty easy.